# Why am I getting variable not declared

Tags: javascript

I have the following in my partial view...

```
@Model.ServerDetails
<div>
..... various markup
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bs = '@Model.BackupServer';
    if (bs == null) {
        bs = "";
    }
    var bssn = bs + '|' + '@Model.ServerName';

    $(document).ready( function() {
        if (bs != "") {
          $getJSON('@UrlContent("~/Details/OtherBackedUpServers?bsn=" + bssn)', function(returnedServers) {
             ..... removed for brevity...
          }
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately **bssn** in the **$getJSON()** paramater is showing an error: 'bssn' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Can someone explain why and how I can correct it?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are mixing up serverside code and clientside code

Comment: You can't pass a client side variable to a server side function. The server code gets evaluated before the page is even sent to client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or write:

```
$getJSON('@UrlContent("OtherBackedUpServers", "Details")?bsn=' + bssn, function(returnedServers) {
             ..... removed for brevity...
          }
```

**CORRECTION**

```
$getJSON('@Url.Action("OtherBackedUpServers", "Details")?bsn=' + bssn, function(returnedServers) {
             ..... removed for brevity...
          }
```

Comment: Split between who gave the right answer... Used this one but with Url.Action instead of Url.Content which is probably an oversight.

Comment: My bad - just used Copy&Paste ;) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass JavaScript(Client Side) variable to `Url.Action` as it is processed at the Server-Side.

As a workaround, you can use placeholder to generate the url. Then use `.replace()` method to generate the actual url.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("OtherBackedUpServers", "Details", new { bsn= -1})';
url = url .replace('-1', bssn);
$.getJSON(url );
```

---

Or, Better pass the variable as payload

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("OtherBackedUpServers", "Details")', { bsn : -1});
```